# How do I observe the current selected view inside <my-view1> in PSK?

Tags: polymer-starter-kit

In Polymer-Starter-Kit, how do I observe the current selected view inside `<my-view1>`, so that I can create an observer and only trigger it whenever the `<my-view>` is selected/visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the iron-pages element, include the attribute "selected-attribute" like this:

```
<iron-pages
  selected="[[page]]"
  attr-for-selected="name"
  fallback-selection="view404"
  selected-attribute="selected"
  role="main">
```

and in each of the views, include a property named "selected". You can set an observer to this selected property. It will be true when the page is shown and false otherwise.

Comment: I intend to set an observer inside `<my-view1>` instead of `<my-app>`.

Comment: Yeah, that is correct. Create a property named "selected" inside my-view1 and set an observer to "selected".